# Create a News Feed that displays posts from people they are following

Tags: php, sql

I have a code that should check the Database `following` to find all the people that the current logged in user has followed then it will search the second database `posts` to find any posts by the people they are following but it currently only shows one post. I know its not very efficient compared to `JOIN` but I don't fully understand how that works.

Here is a Screenshot of the Database `Following` it has the user who sent the following request and the user they are following what is it should do is use the `session id` for the logged in user and find all matching results for the user in the following column and it should take all the results from the column `following` and search the database `post` in the column `code` and echo all the results as the newsfeed.

[image]

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$myid=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM following WHERE follower='$myid'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$following=$row['following'];
?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($following==$row['code']){
?>
    <div class="content"> 
        <section class="intro">
            <h2><a href="/profile/?id=<?php echo $row['code']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></a></h2>
            <div class="text">
<?php echo $row['post']; ?>
</div>
<?php   
}
else{

}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<?php
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have an empty else block?

Comment: @Qix Because I don't want anything to execute if no posts exist.

Comment: Umm... else is optional. If you don't want to do anything, just leave it out entirely.

Comment: At first glance your code looks fine, other than a few nits. What is in your database? What else have you tried?

Comment: My Database `following` is just numbers each user is given a number when they sign up and when they follow someone its inserted into the database as follower and then the person they are following is in the column following.

Answer (score 0):

Because my previouse answer didnt help What do you want to output??
If your database has 3 followers does it have to output this in html?

But this Code will Output All users in your following list Like this..

```
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts");               

                echo "<div class='content'> <section class='intro'>";
                echo "<h2><a href='/profile/?id=".$row['code']."'>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if ($following==$row['code']){
                echo $row['name']." ".$row['lastname']."</a></h2>";
                echo $row['post'];
                }
                echo "<div class='text'>";
                echo "</div>"; 
              }
```

This Code is Outputting this but the Bold text in this example is a link that goes to
/profile/?id=CODEHERE

**Steve Jobs** <-- is a link (goes to /profile/?id=CODEHERE

The Post text

**Johny John**

The Post text

**Miracle Tru**

The Post text

Comment: Hi thanks for your anwser but That code gives me a syntax error

Comment: @user3621313 Hi i changed my code, can you tell me if this is working for you please :)